# React final form - submit a wizard form on click of a radio button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, final-form

I would like to submit a step of wizard form on click of radio button instead of classic submit button.

Radio component :

```
const Radio = ({ input, children }) => (
  <label className="form-radio city">
    <input {...input} />
    <span className="radio-text">{children}</span>
  </label>
)
```

My class :

```
<ProfileForm.Page>
   {CITIES.map(({ name }) => (
       <Field component={Radio} type="radio" name="city" key={name} value={name}>
           {name}
        </Field>
   ))}
   <button type="submit"></button>
 </ProfileForm.Page>
```

This worked when I use the submit button but I want to remove it and submit city directly on click on the radio button.

Comment: Can't you add an onChange event to the radio button and trigger submit from there ?

Comment: Hello, I answer you below, thanks for your help :)

Comment: @gui35 - there is no answer below. Don't keep Damini waiting. Update (edit) your question with the outcome.

Comment: @Kevin Buchs - my problem is not solve, I have add precision with my code

Answer (score 0):

I tried to had an onChange event with "this.form.submit()" but I cannot acced to "form".

I have a parent component ***ProfileForm.jsx*** with :

```
 <Form validate={this.validate} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} initialValues={values}>
    {({ handleSubmit, invalid, pristine, values }) => (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            {activePage}   
        </form>
    )}
 </Form>
```

and my radio buttons are on the "active page" ***City.jsx*** with the code of my first post

Comment: Try passing the form as a prop? If you have the onChange can I see both the components code :)